# Parse large JSON file in Nodejs FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

Tags: node.js, json, heroku, stream, strapi

I try to populate strapi database with large json file (4,6Mo),

It is working in local but when I deploy to Heroku (`Hobby Basic`)

I got this error:

***src/index.js***

```js
"use strict";
const path = require("path");
const dataDirectory = path.resolve(process.cwd(), "data");
const JsonPath = path.join(dataDirectory, "places.json");
const StreamArray = require("stream-json/streamers/StreamArray");
const fs = require("fs");

module.exports = {
  async bootstrap({ strapi }) {
    if (!(await strapi.entityService.count("api::place.place"))) {
      strapi.log.info("Create place ");
      const pipeline = fs
        .createReadStream(JsonPath)
        .pipe(StreamArray.withParser());
      pipeline.on("data", async (data) => {
        await strapi.entityService.create("api::place.place", {
          data: data.value,
        });
      });
    } else {
      strapi.log.info("Place ready ");
    }
  },
};
```

***console error***

```
2022-01-18T00:40:24.566747+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-01-18 00:40:24.566] info: Create place 
2022-01-18T00:40:40.028542+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2022-01-18T00:40:40.028550+00:00 app[web.1]: <--- Last few GCs --->
2022-01-18T00:40:40.028551+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2022-01-18T00:40:40.028566+00:00 app[web.1]: [22:0x646cfd0]    16102 ms: Mark-sweep (reduce) 249.6 (258.2) -> 247.6 (258.2) MB, 803.9 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.165, current mu = 0.089) allocation failure scavenge might not succeed
2022-01-18T00:40:40.028567+00:00 app[web.1]: [22:0x646cfd0]    16974 ms: Mark-sweep (reduce) 248.6 (258.2) -> 247.9 (258.2) MB, 867.2 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.088, current mu = 0.005) allocation failure scavenge might not succeed
2022-01-18T00:40:40.028567+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2022-01-18T00:40:40.028567+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2022-01-18T00:40:40.028567+00:00 app[web.1]: <--- JS stacktrace --->
2022-01-18T00:40:40.028568+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2022-01-18T00:40:40.028574+00:00 app[web.1]: FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
2022-01-18T00:40:40.029368+00:00 app[web.1]: 1: 0xb00d90 node::Abort() [node]
2022-01-18T00:40:40.029964+00:00 app[web.1]: 2: 0xa1823b node::FatalError(char const*, char const*) [node]
2022-01-18T00:40:40.030637+00:00 app[web.1]: 3: 0xcedbce v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [node]
2022-01-18T00:40:40.031291+00:00 app[web.1]: 4: 0xcedf47 v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [node]
2022-01-18T00:40:40.031941+00:00 app[web.1]: 5: 0xea6105  [node]
2022-01-18T00:40:40.032555+00:00 app[web.1]: 6: 0xea6be6  [node]
2022-01-18T00:40:40.033131+00:00 app[web.1]: 7: 0xeb4b1e  [node]
2022-01-18T00:40:40.033724+00:00 app[web.1]: 8: 0xeb5560 v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage(v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::GarbageCollectionReason, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [node]
2022-01-18T00:40:40.034294+00:00 app[web.1]: 9: 0xeb84de v8::internal::Heap::AllocateRawWithRetryOrFailSlowPath(int, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [node]
2022-01-18T00:40:40.034878+00:00 app[web.1]: 10: 0xe7990a v8::internal::Factory::NewFillerObject(int, bool, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin) [node]
2022-01-18T00:40:40.035544+00:00 app[web.1]: 11: 0x11f2f06 v8::internal::Runtime_AllocateInYoungGeneration(int, unsigned long*, v8::internal::Isolate*) [node]
2022-01-18T00:40:40.036316+00:00 app[web.1]: 12: 0x15e7819  [node]
2022-01-18T00:40:40.061945+00:00 app[web.1]: Aborted
2022-01-18T00:40:40.205401+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 134
2022-01-18T00:40:40.365837+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

Thank you very much if you have any suggestions or ideas to resolve this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `data` event will be emitted each time a chunk is processed without considering whether an entity has been inserted.
So data events will be emitted much faster than strapi can process it.

See [Backpressuring in Streams](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/backpressuring-in-streams) for more informations

You should use core [pipeline](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#streampipelinesource-transforms-destination-callback) function with a custom writable stream and call `done` when entity has been created :

```
const { pipeline } = require("stream/promises");

await pipeline(
  fs.createReadStream(JsonPath),
  StreamArray.withParser(),
  new Writable({
    objectMode: true,
    write: (data, _, done) => {
      strapi.entityService
        .create("api::place.place", {
          data: data.value,
        })
        .then(() => done());
    },
  })
);
```

Note that you can also use [oleoduc](https://github.com/bguerout/oleoduc) (*i'm the author*). This tiny library provides utils to easily stream data.

```
const { oleoduc, writeData } = require("oleoduc");

await oleoduc(
  fs.createReadStream(JsonPath),
  StreamArray.withParser(),
  writeData((data) => {
    return strapi.entityService.create("api::place.place", {
      data: data.value,
    });
  })
);
```